# Cloned objects aren't equal

Tags: java, clone

Trying to implement deep copy, but when I test my method in the main with equal() it comes up false though all of the data is the same.

This is my clone method:

```
  @Override
    public Object clone() { try {
            // shallow copy
            BankAccount clone = (BankAccount)super.clone();
            // deep copy
            clone.createDate = (java.util.Date)(createDate.clone());

            return clone;
        }
        catch (CloneNotSupportedException y) {
           return null; }
```

This is my main for testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount(1111, 5347);
        BankAccount account2 = (BankAccount)account1.clone();

        System.out.println(account2.equals(account1));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the equals method for your object. By default the equals method of any objects compares the addresses of both objects.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to Charles' answer, you have to override `public boolean equals(Object obj)` method of your `BankAccount` class.

And below is an example for your reference:

```java
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    static class BankAccount implements Cloneable {
        private int id;
        private int balance;
        private Date createDate;
        
        public BankAccount(int id, int balance) {
            this.id = id;
            this.balance = balance;
            this.createDate = new Date();
        }
        
        public int getId() { return id; }
        public int getBalance() { return balance; }
        
        @Override
        public Object clone() { 
            try {
                // shallow copy
                BankAccount clone = (BankAccount)super.clone();
                // deep copy
                clone.createDate = (java.util.Date)(createDate.clone());

                return clone;
            } catch (CloneNotSupportedException y) {
                y.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
        
        // You have to override this function for value comparison
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            // Check if the passing Object is BankAccount
            if (!(obj instanceof BankAccount))
                return false;
                
            BankAccount otherBankAccount = (BankAccount) obj;
            // You need to define your own comparison criteria to determine
            //  whether 2 BankAccounts are equal
            if (otherBankAccount.getId() == this.getId() 
                && otherBankAccount.getBalance() == this.getBalance())
                return true;
            
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount(1111, 5347);
        BankAccount account2 = (BankAccount)account1.clone();
        BankAccount account3 = new BankAccount(1111, 5347);
        BankAccount account4 = new BankAccount(1234, 5347);
        
        System.out.println(account2.equals(account1));
        System.out.println(account3.equals(account2));
        System.out.println(account4.equals(account2));
    }
}
```

Output:

> true
> true
> false